# App for Cropping and Resizing an image

Tags: applications, display, crop

Is there an application where I can crop an image then resize it into custom dimensions?

I would like to crop it like with the built in Command+Shift+4 , then in a window I could select the dimensions.

So is there an app for this?

Answer (score 4):

But of course [Preview](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2506)!

To **resize**: *Choose Tools > Adjust Size, then enter the size you want to change the image to, then click OK*

To **crop**: *Click the "Select", then click and drag to select the area of the image that you want to retain. Next, choose Tools > Crop or press Command-K. If you crop too much, you can press Command-Z or choose Edit > Undo to undo the crop.*

Answer (score 1):

i use Skitch for simple image resizing and cropping. Saves tons of time. [www.skitch.com](http://www.skitch.com)